# Crashing when 4 images

Tags: android, imageview

the app is not crashing when I have 3 ImageViews but when I am adding a 4th or 5th ImageView its crashing. So what can I do that I can even have about 50 pictures in this HorizontalScrollView. Do I need to change the heap size?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/black"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

<ImageView 
    android:layout_width="200dp"    
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:src="@drawable/wp2"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/display"
    />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="15dp"
    android:text="Als Hintergrundbild festlegen" />

<HorizontalScrollView android:layout_width="200dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="center">
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal">
<ImageView 
    android:layout_width="125dp"    
    android:layout_height="125dp"
    android:id="@+id/wp1"
    android:padding="15dp"
    />
<ImageView 
    android:layout_width="125dp"    
    android:layout_height="125dp"
    android:id="@+id/wp2"
    android:padding="15dp"
    />
<ImageView 
    android:layout_width="125dp"    
    android:layout_height="125dp"
    android:id="@+id/wp3"
    android:padding="15dp"
/>
<ImageView 
    android:layout_width="125dp"    
    android:layout_height="125dp"
    android:id="@+id/wp4"
    android:padding="15dp"
/>

</LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Crashes means? Do you have an error or better a logcat message?

Comment: LogcatNotFoundException?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably running into the issue that your app is running out of memory. You can add `android:largeHeap="true"`to your application tag in your `AndroidManifest.xml`, but I don't recommend this. I recommend reading [this](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html) article on the Android Developer website. It shows you how to load big bitmaps effectively, which should reduce the memory usage by your app and makes it a better experience for the user.

Answer (score 0):

If you are adding a large number of images you may be better using a ListView and creating a ListViewAdapter to display your images. This has the advantage that you won't have to manually add all the imageviews, and Android will reuse the views in the ListViewAdapter to help manage the memory. I don't know if they can be displayed horizontally. Make sure you are displaying a scaled down version of the image - don't just load it as it is. For example, something like:

```
public static Bitmap GetThumbnail(string fullPath, int width, int height)
    {
        Bitmap bMap = null;
        try
        {
            Bitmap src = BitmapFactory.DecodeFile(fullPath);

            bMap = Bitmap.CreateScaledBitmap(src, width, height, false);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.WriteLog("An error occurred producing a bitmap for file [" + fullPath + "]: " + ex.Message, ELogType.FILE);
        }
        return bMap;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look on this android tutorials - [Displaying Bitmaps Efficiently](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html) . Problems with bitmaps is common for android.